# Why do we want to keep mantissa as small as possible and exponent as large as possible?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Why do we want to keep mantissa as small as possible and exponent as large as possible in the floating point representation of numbers?

What would happen if we make mantissa as big as possible?

Note:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQF1Bg-ykRA&list=PLYdroRCLMg5O-SZZL8kqFkcjWllPVpmXc&index=10

NUMERICALMETHODS FOR ENGINEERS, SIXTH EDITION by Chapra & Canale. Page-64 to 65

Comment: But we do not want the mantissa as small as possible, do we?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen,  NUMERICALMETHODS FOR ENGINEERS, SIXTH EDITION by Chapra & Canale. Page-64 to 65.

Comment: I don't think we want it as small as possible. However, it is a trade-off between range of sizes (determined by the exponent) and accuracy (determined by the mantissa).

Comment: It may be the other way. we certainly don't want $0.00042\times 10^{10}$,

Comment: It looks like you have misunderstood something. Please explain why you think that we want to keep the mantissa as small as possible and the exponent as large as possible.

Comment: @TonyK, please watch the video. At (03:43) it says that "We would try to keep our magnitude as big as possible and Mantissa as small as possible".

Comment: If you rewind to 3:06 in that video, you will see that the lecturer is constructing the smallest possible positive number. And for this, then yes, you want the (magnitude of the) exponent to be as large as possible and the mantissa as small as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In floating point numbers,
the mantissa is normalized
so it is less than one
in absolute value.

So this question
is based on 
an incorrect assumption.

The representation is of the form
$\text{mantissa} * \text{base}^{\text{exponent}}$
with the exponent usually biased
so it fits more nicely
into however many bits it uses.

The mantissa can be made *smaller*,
usually by some power of the base,
and this requires the exponent
to be made correspondingly larger.
These numbers are called
*un-normalized*.

There is a whole lot more
in the discussion of
floating point arithmetic.
Of course, Knuth has a bunch.

Another name to search for 
is Kahan.